# Using jmeter to place messages on google-cloud pubsub

Tags: jmeter, google-cloud-pubsub

Has anyone had success in using Jmeter to load messages onto Google PubSub. I can’t find much on the web about this topic. There is a GCP pubSub plugin but it does not have a lot of instructions on how to use it.
Can JMS Publisher be used?
I don’t have much experience with any of the above.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is following official documentation: [Quickstart: Using Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#pubsub-client-libraries-java)

1. [Install Maven](https://maven.apache.org/install.html)
2. Create *pom.xml* file with the following content anywhere in your hard drive

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

       <groupId>org.example</groupId>
       <artifactId>untitled</artifactId>
       <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

       <dependencyManagement>
           <dependencies>
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                   <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                   <version>20.2.0</version>
                   <type>pom</type>
                   <scope>import</scope>
               </dependency>
           </dependencies>
       </dependencyManagement>

       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
               <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>


   </project>
   ```
3. Execute the [copy-dependencies command](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) in the folder where pom.xml lives:

   ```
   mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
   ```
4. Copy everything from `target/dependency` folder to ["lib" folder of your JMeter installation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
5. Restart JMeter if it's running
6. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your Test Plan
7. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import com.google.api.core.ApiFuture
   import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher
   import com.google.protobuf.ByteString
   import com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage
   import com.google.pubsub.v1.TopicName
   import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit


   // TODO(developer): Replace these variables before running the sample.
   String projectId = 'your-project-id'
   String topicId = 'your-topic-id'

   TopicName topicName = TopicName.of(projectId, topicId)

   Publisher publisher = null
   try {
       // Create a publisher instance with default settings bound to the topic
       publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName).build()

       String message = 'Hello World!'
       ByteString data = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(message)
       PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setData(data).build()

       // Once published, returns a server-assigned message id (unique within the topic)
       ApiFuture<String> messageIdFuture = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage)
       String messageId = messageIdFuture.get()
       log.info('Published message ID: ' + messageId)
   } finally {
       if (publisher != null) {
           // When finished with the publisher, shutdown to free up resources.
           publisher.shutdown()
           publisher.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
       }
   }
   ```
8. Replace `your-project-id` and `your-topic-id` with your own values
9. Run your test - it should post `Hello world` message to the given project/topic

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Later on you can follow instructions from [How to write a plugin for JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html) to make this functionality available "natively"